# How to extract date and month part from datetime field in database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, datetime

I have a datetime column named `submitted_date`. One of it's value in database is *5/12/2017 11:09:50 AM*. Now I want to extract only date and month part of it. How to display it in a format like "May-12".
My code is here,

```
   using (SqlConnection con = obj.getcon())
    {
        con.Open();
        string query = "SELECT submitted_date FROM sample";
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string x_val = reader[0].ToString(); // 5/12/2017 11:09:50 AM
                }
            }
        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the alphabetic month name you can use `MMM`. Here is the code:

```
var result = DateTime.Parse(reader[0].ToString())  
                     .ToString("MMMM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
//if reader[0].ToString(): 5/12/2017 11:09:50 AM then
//result: May-12
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DATEPART directly on SQL and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the following, but you will need to know which culture so as to get the month name in the correct language. I have used the US culture in this example:

```
string s = reader.GetDateTime(0).ToString("MMMM-dd", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
```

This also assumes that your submitted_date column is NOT NULL.

Answer (score 0):

**You can write query like:**
Convert(varchar(20),submitted_date,107) submitted_date which will return date on Dec 12, 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**from:**

```
string x_val = reader[0].ToString(); // 5/12/2017 11:09:50 AM
```

**To:**

```
string x_val =DateTime.Parse(reader[0].ToString()).ToString("MMM-dd");
```